# How to define and use contact groups/mailing lists in mu4e?

Tags: mu4e

How can I conveniently define and use contact groups/mailing lists when using mu4e?

For example I want to define a group "tennis club" which contains multiple email addresses

- roger.federer@tennis.com
- pete.sampras@tennis.com
- boris.becker@tennis.com

...

Then I want to select "tennis club" (with auto completion) when writing an email (such that the mail will be send to all members of this group).

Regarding auto-completion I would like to see it integrated to helm, which is the completion interface I am currently using.

For comparison: In thunderbird this feature is called "[mailing list](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-create-and-use-mailing-lists-thunderbird)".

Answer (score 1):

I have a `.mailrc` with:

```
alias foo "PersonA <a@a.com>" "B <b@b.com>"
alias bar ...
```

I do not have autocomplete, but if I type "foo<ENTER>" in the `To:` field, it replaces `foo` with the list of email addresses.

You could also use yasnippet?

Comment: Thanks. I had to invoke `rebuild-mail-abbrevs` to make it work.

Comment: Regarding completion I don't see why yasnippet would be a good idea, because then you have to define the snippets manually. It might be better to use helm or something like this to generate dynamically a candidate list.

Comment: yasnippet is powerful. You could have one snippet called 'list' that parses .mailrc and does autocompletion options for you, so you type list<tab> to invoke yasnippet, then are presented with a menue. Could also use hydra and have a small menu of completions.